# Cannot change the background on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, desktop-background

[image]

Hi everyone, I cannot change the background on Ubuntu 20.04, the background is black, but when I check "Show Applications", there's the background.

[image]

Comment: Have u tried to configure via cli or gui tools like dconf-editor related to background?

Comment: whats the output of the command `gsettings list-recursively | grep picture-uri`

Comment: @UnKNOWn org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///usr/share/themes/Adwaita/backgrounds/adwaita-timed.xml'
org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png'
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver picture-uri 'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png'